# How to bind spinner in android using sqlite?

Tags: android

I have a table containing

```
------------------------
id    |Name
------------------------
16001 |ABC
16002 |QWE
16003 |RTY
16004 |JHG
```

and bind it to a spinner; spinner item with name, and spinneritemposition with id.

I try this so far:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button 
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_ite‌​m);
    List<String> lables = dataSource.getAllmothers();

    public List<String> getAllmothers()
    {
       List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
       database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "SELECT id,name FROM "+dbHelper.TABLE_REGISTRATION;
       Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); // looping through all rows and adding to list 
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        do
         { 
          labels.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0)));
          labels.add(cursor.getString(1)); 
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
      } // closing connection
      cursor.close(); 
      database.close(); // returning lables

   return labels; 
 }
```

Comment: First try yourself and then ask here if you face any problem.

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: spinner show all the items id and name alternatively

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: but i want name as item part
and id as a position part

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
        
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: List<String> lables = dataSource.getAllmothers();

Comment: public List<String> getAllmothers(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT id,name FROM "+dbHelper.TABLE_REGISTRATION;
    
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
             labels.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0)));

Comment: you must right your custom adapter

Comment: labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        database.close();
        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }

Comment: How Mr.Shayan pourvatan..

Comment: see http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-39-create-custom-spinner-in-android/ and http://www.edureka.in/blog/custom-spinner-in-android/

Comment: if you don't understand see this too http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Answer (score 0):

create Array Adapter like this
ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(cureentclass,dropdownstyle,values)

values is what u r getting through the database values variable and add the bind the Array Adapter to the spinner.